# apt update failure: NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2

Tags: updates, googledart

How can I fix this error with update:

```
Err:26 https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release.gpg
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2
<omitted>
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2
W: Failed to fetch https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dists/stable/Release.gpg  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo gpg  --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/dart.gpg
```

This downloads key and put it under /usr/share/keyrings/.
Remove the old sources.list for thise repo under /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

```
echo 'deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/dart.gpg arch=amd64] https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list
```

This creates the new one and try again.

Comment: Is there a link to any docs that verifies this is the correct key for dart?

Comment: https://dart.dev/get-dart#install Here.

Comment: why save it in /usr/share/keyrings/ instead of /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ as intended? Is there an advantage to that approach?

Comment: @Ira I was just following the install instruction from webpage.

Answer (score 2):

If these errors aren’t fixed, apt will have problems when installing or upgrading packages.
The apt packaging system has a set of trusted keys that determine whether a package can be authenticated and therefore trusted to be installed on the system.
There is a quick fix.

Looking at the error above, apt is telling us that the following key is missing: `E88979FB9B30ACF2`
To add these key, run the following command:

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E88979FB9B30ACF2`

If the key that your system is missing differs, simply replace the key at the end of the above command with your key and run it.